# .php files breaking when php tag added. Worked before, not today

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Hello fellow computer people!

I'm currently working on a project for my degree course and I'm making a website for a local club. Most of the front end is complete now so I thought this would be a good point to implement the log in functions.

Been watching a few videos and freehosting a few mock tests but now I've hit a problem...

I'm following a youtube guide on the PHP and MySQL parts but as soon as I write in the PHP tags my website breaks.

The current file I've added the PHP tag to is a .php file so it's not that it's the wrong format, but instead of loading the HTML parts and executing the PHP parts the browser instead displays the whole file as it is written in the text editor.

Please find below my snippets with and without the PHP to see if I'm doing something wrong.

**File name login.php (No PHP) (WORKS)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Login</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/authcss.css">
</head>
<body>

 <div class="return">
  <a href="index.html">Cleethorpes Lightnings</a>
 </div>

 <h1>Login</h1>
 <span>or <a href="register.php">register here</a></span>

 <form action="login.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email">
  <input type="password" placeholder="And your password" name="password">
  <input type="submit">
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**File name login.php (With PHP) (BROKEN)**

```html
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['email'])):
 echo ($_POST['email']);
 die();
endif;


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Login</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/authcss.css">
</head>
<body>

 <div class="return">
  <a href="index.html">Cleethorpes Lightnings</a>
 </div>

 <h1>Login</h1>
 <span>or <a href="register.php">register here</a></span>

 <form action="login.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email">
  <input type="password" placeholder="And your password" name="password">
  <input type="submit">
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for any support you can offer me!
Shaun.

Comment: Annoyingly, I can see that if I run the snippet on here it works fine, however trying to run the same code in my browser still doesn't work.

Comment: PHP doesn't run in the browser at all.

Comment: I thing you have to install xampp or wamp in your local computer

Comment: check php installed in your system by using this command     php -r 'echo "\n\nYour PHP installation is working fine.\n\n\n";'

Comment: @Saik3037 — Command line `php` executables and versions of PHP intergrated with a web server are often entirely independant. That is not a useful test.

Comment: Still not sure why previous tests and trails have worked but this one isn't. This is both running locally and through my freehost. Very confused now

Comment: Also running this file in the freehost alerts my antivirus...? Not sure why that's happening.